# Find out an item is clicked in listView in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have approx 150 items in my custom listview. I am trying to implement the following:

**list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {**

**1. I get position of the item**

**2. Get the data from an ArrayList**

**3. Add the data to database.**

**This part is working fine.**

But if I want to remove a particular item from the database by clicking on the item I am not able to achieve this part?

Reason because I am not sure if the item is clicked or not? I have this problem mainly when I want to implement search in the listView and add the selected item to database and remove selected item from database.

```
    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) 
        {

            if (notfromsearch == true)
            {
                String profile_ID = profileList.get(position).get(KEY_ID);
                String profile_DISPLAY_NAME = profileList.get(position).get(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME);
              //add to database now

            }
            elseif (notfromsearch == false)
            {
                String SearchResult_profile_ID = searchProfileResults.get(position).get(KEY_ID);
                String SearchRResult_profile_DISPLAY_NAME = searchProfileResults.get(position).get(KEY_DISPLAY_NAME);
                //add to database now
            }
        }
    });
```

But how to implement remove from database? I am not able to differentiate if the item is clicked before or not to remove from database.

Can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your ArrayList contains **Strings** or **CustomObjects** ??

Comment: Arraylist contains ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> profileList;.

Answer (score 0):

On your list view, use

> setOnItemClickListener

and you can do what you want next .

Comment: I have setOnitemClick things are working fine if I select the item but I am not sure how to unselect the item if I want to remove the data from database?

Comment: You question is not clear enough sir , maybe you need to take a look at this question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103721/unselect-the-listview-item-onclick-in-android

Comment: Please read my question again Sir you will understand. I have list of items shown in custom listview. when i select it I would like to add corresponding data to database. (This part is working fine) but if I want unselect the item (remove data from database) how do i implement this part on the same setOnItemclickListener

Answer (score 0):

use `context menu` for deleting items from the `database`

on `long press` display `delete/edit` option and perform further operation as needed.

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632331/using-contextmenu-with-listview-in-android) for context menu sample

**EDIT**

You can also put `button/image` in the `listview` to `delete` item and then implement your `delete` operation in the `click` method.

For Checkbox selection

model class

```
class CustomClass
{
     boolean checked;
     //other fields
}
```

in your custom adapter class

```
ArrayList<CustomClass> data = new ArrayList<CustomClass>();
```

and in `getView()` method

```
checkboxItem.setChecked(data.get(position).getChecked());
```

and don't forget to change the `checked boolean` value on `checkbox change listener`..

Comment: I don't want to implement long press part.

Comment: hey! Is this the only way to differentiate the add and delete?

Comment: I did try that out, but I had a strange issue: I added checked box to the custom ListView. The data was showing fine, but the strange issue is that when I check the first row in my list and scroll down I can see another item checked. This is happening everything 7th item on my list. The item is checked automatically. I couldn't solve that issue hence was looking for different solution

Comment: i did have the same kind of issue and i think i solved that using custom model class with additional boolean field checked which was used for checking/unchecking the checkbox.

Comment: can you help me with a sample project on this?

Comment: Oh Sorry I don't have sample project at this moment.. i will post if i find free time...